# JodaTime setCurrentMillisFixed(millis) not working as thought

Tags: java, junit, jodatime

I am playing around with Joda Time for a JUnit Test in order to "bypass" the Timeout Window in my code. I don't really seem to get how Joda Time works - my code:

```
// TIMEOUT is "1000 * 90"
long Time = System.currentTimeMillis();
DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed(Time + TIMEOUT + 1);
DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisSystem();
System.out.println((Time+TIMEOUT) < System.currentTimeMillis());
```

The output is false and I would have expected it to be true. So where did I go wrong?

Comment: Setting Joda time's millis only affects libraries that use JodaTime. It won't affect JUnit, which calls System.currentTimeMillis (a native method that can't really be overridden by a library in any meaningful way). Did you read the javadocs for DateTimeUtils?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed()` does not change the result of `System.currentTimeMillis()`

The idea is all your code where you would have called `System.currentTimeMillis()` should instead use `DateTimeUtils.currentTimeMillis()` which by default calls `System.currentTimeMillis()` unless you told it to use a fixed timestamp.

Furthermore, most code that uses a timeout will call `System.currentTimeMillis()` directly so you can't use Jodatime to change timeout periods.

The intent of the Jodatime methods is to be able to better test code that is date or time dependent.  For example, if my code does something different after work hours or on the weekend, I can have my test code make it look like it is whatever time I want to test (as long as the code uses `DateTimeUtils.currentTimeMillis()` to see what the time/date is.)

Also `DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisSystem();` changes the DateTimeUtils.currentTimeMillis() method to go back to using System.currentTimeMillis() instead of whatever you set the fixed time to.  So even if JodaTime behaved like you thought it would, you would have reset the time back before your test assertion anyway